# Javascript Wordpress | How to implement window.history.pushState ()

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I explain the problem I am using inside my site, a form in frontend ajax, which works perfectly and gives the user an optimal user experience, so that the user can have fun without any problem through the filters to find the product that he needs most.

And this works perfectly, the problem is that it generates an error during navigation.

Error:

Let's assume that a user searches for a product in Chicago, plays with the price filter in ascending or descending order and finds a product, enters the product page, consults it and then returns to the search page, and as if by magic, poof, the search form is empty, because ajax grants a perfect user experience to the user but does not keep in memory nor filters nor values ​​searched in the form previously, so to solve this problem I wanted to integrate within the script that regulates the ajax form: `window.history.pushState()`

so that every time the user searches for something or simply applies a filter the url changes, it follows that if the user visits the product page and returns to the search the values ​​via a `$_GET` of the url, they will show him what he has been looking for before.

Structure of the ajax form

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
  
<input style="padding-top: 25px;margin-right: 15px;"  type="search" id="research-autocomplete" value="" name="categoryfilter" aria-describedby="button-addon4" class="form-control bg- border-0">

   <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="order"><option value="">
      <option value="ASC">Prezzo Crescente</option>
      <option value="DESC">Prezzo Decrescente</option>
     
    </select>
                                
<input type="checkbox" name="firts" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked">
<button>Apply filter</button>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
</form>
```

and:

```
<div id="response"></div>
```

functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'ajax_filter_function'); // wp_ajax_{ACTION HERE}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'ajax_filter_function');

function ajax_filter_function(){
        $args =  array(
            'post_type' => 'pro',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_key'    => $_POST['categoryfilter'],
            'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
            'order'       => $_POST['order'],
        );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) :

        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
          /*SOME DATA SHOW PRODUCT*/
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;

}
```

script:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('#filter').submit(function(){
            var filter = $('#filter');
            $.ajax({
                url:filter.attr('action'),
                data:filter.serialize(), // form data
                type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
                beforeSend:function(xhr){
                    filter.find('button').text('Processing...'); // changing the button label
                },
                success:function(data){
                    filter.find('button').text('Apply filter'); // changing the button label back
                    $('#response').html(data); // insert data
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

not having much knowledge in javascript how i can implement: `window.history.pushState()` in my script for solve this problem?

Comment: Tray this `window.history.pushState({filter}, `Selected: ${filter}`, `${'page=' +  filter}`)`

Comment: @Mantykora7 if I copy and paste your code it doesn't work, am I doing something wrong in the configuration of your code?

Comment: And what do you have in the console, what do you send in POST?

Comment: @Mantykora7 nothing because if i copy and paste: window.history.pushState({filter}, Selected: ${filter}, ${'page=' + filter}) or window.history.pushState({filter}, ${filter}, ${'page=' + filter}), this code broke my form and console not show anything cause redirect to: wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: The `filter` variable is a jQuery object. The [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) method requires a state object and then two strings. So of course trying to supply an object where string is expected will crash the app.

Comment: Can you make your project public?

Comment: @Mantykora7 window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url"); my page name is: results, how to pass in new-url data from form?

Comment: @Mantykora7 if u invite me in chat i can explain

Comment: You will have to rebuild the url with the params. Take your current url and replace the filter values.

Comment: @El_Vanja friend, hi, i was trying to solve the problem i showed you two days ago with pushstate don't you think this is a good idea?

Comment: I'm leaving in a moment.

Comment: @El_Vanja can't I pass the selected values ​​in the form to window.history.pushState and modify the url accordingly?

Comment: It's a good idea, but you have to build the url manually. It's a dirty solution, but currently there's no way around it.

Comment: @El_Vanja the problem that having no knowledge in js I don't know how to pass the values ​​of the form to the pushstate in fact in the question I have also published the name of my form fields to get help

Comment: I'm not familiar with `history.pushState`, I'm just reading the docs. I'd have to try and develop a simple example before I can further help.

Comment: @El_Vanja ok because the example was to pass: categoryfilter and the other data of the form so that doing the $ _POST of the data chosen in the form consequently went to the url and then I recovered them in $ _GET, but I can't understand how to get the value of the form and grant it to the url

Comment: You have to build a function and get last part of url e.g `var url_string = window.location.href;` `var url_parts = url_string.split('/');`, `var piece = url_parts[url_parts.length -1]; `

Comment: @Mantykora7 i have no idea how this can be done, i have no js knowledge

Comment: publish your work somewhere on some test server that will be easier  (AWS)`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7xBdiGFP0U`

Comment: By the way, you need to know something about js, no one will write for you, possibly correct the code. And url in js is heavy weight.

Comment: @Mantykora7 I don't see any other way, to be able to solve this problem of mine, do you know other ways?